# how to sort chart according to grid sort,for the same data

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

i have a chart and grid having the same data,i want my chart to be sorted when i sort the grid by clicking on sort option ,for example:

here is the dataSource:

```
 var Data= [
    { id: 1, name: "Jane Do", age: 30 },
    { id: 2, name: "John Doe", age: 33 }
  ];
```

here is the grid:

```
 $("#grid").kendoGrid({
columns: [
  { field: "name" },
  { field: "age" }
],
dataSource: {
  data:Data

},
sortable: true,
 sort: function(e) {
  console.log(e.sort.field);
  console.log(e.sort.dir);
}  
 });
```

here is the chart:

```
 $("#chart").kendoChart({

dataSource: {
    data: Data,

},

series: [{
    type: "column",
    field: "age",
    categoryField: "name"
}],     
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the same grid sorting options to the chart:

```
sort: function(e) {
    $("#chart").data("kendoChart").dataSource.sort(e.sort);
}
```

[Demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/akOXijuS)